# Read local JSON file with Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, readfile

How can read local json file with Vuejs?
This is my simple JSON file:

(someJSON.json)

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "description": "Dafgard project backup",
    "name": "Dafgard",
    "avatar_url": null,
    "commit_count": 0,
    "last_activity_at": 1418820265000
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "description": "dafgard.net repo",
    "name": "dafgardDotNet",
    "avatar_url": null,
    "commit_count": 0,
    "last_activity_at": 1441780268000
  }
```

and now I read this file when start tomcat server with response

```
<script>
export default {
        created: function() {
            this.refreshProjects()
        })
    },
    methods: {
       refreshProjects() {
          console.log(this)
           let vm = this
            // http://localhost:8080
            fetch('/Teamify/Testing/api/some').then((response) => response.json()).then(json => {
            => response.json()).then(json => {
                vm.projects = json
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

so, i want to read this file locally.

I will be glad if someone helps me with some piece of code :)

Comment: is `vm.projects` already defined in `data`? before you make the ajax call?

Comment: yes is defined in data. My application now is work, it's have a back-end part and frond-end, becouse every time when change something from UI i must stop and start tomcat again. My purpose is to seperate front-end from back-end and for this i must read locally json files, but don't have idea. I research every forum but I did not find anything

Comment: `let vm = this`, you don't need to do this when using arrow functions.

Comment: Just import it where you need it `import test from "./test.json";`
Then use test anywhere in component scope

Comment: I tried to import file. For example i tried this -->
import test from "./test.json"

function(){
 return
  test
}